# What's the difference between to_string() and as_a(string) in specman?

Tags: type-conversion, aspect, specman

In Specman I can convert a variable to a string using either:

```
x.to_string();
```

or

```
x.as_a(string);
```

Is there any difference between the two?  If not, why does Specman provide both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`as_a()` allows you to convert the expression to a specific type, not only string.

These are few examples from the [docs](http://www.asic-world.com/specman/data_types2.html)

```
list_of_int.as_a(string)
list_of_byte.as_a(string)
string.as_a(list of int)
string.as_a(list of byte)
bool = string.as_a(bool) (Only TRUE and FALSE can be converted to Boolean; all other strings return an error)
string = bool.as_a(string)
enum = string.as_a(enum)
string = enum.as_a(string)
```

#### UPDATE:

using `as_a(string)` and `to_string()` not always gives the same results.

```
var s: string;
s = "hello";
var lint: list of int;
lint = s.as_a(list of int);
print lint;
print lint.as_a(string);
print lint.to_string();
```

This will print something like this:

```
lint =
  104
  101
  108
  108
  111
lint.as_a(string) = "hello"
list.to_string() = "104 101 108 108 111"
```

This is because `to_string` will run on each element of the list and then the list will be concatenated with spaces, `as_a` will however convert integers to characters and concatenate them, giving you the `hello` word.

Comment: so why is there a separate `to_string()` method?  Is there any advantage to using it?

Comment: This methods not always behave the same. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks!  So if `lint` isn't a list or an integer they should be the same?  For instance if it's an enum?

Comment: In some cases (maybe even most of them) the result may be exactly the same. If you need type conversion you should use `as_a(string)`, if you want text representation of an object use `to_string()`.

Comment: to_string() may also be over-written for structs and units, though I'm not sure if the overriding of to_string() affects as_a(string).